# Giving a scalar and vector function to ND solve?

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, numerics

I'm trying to solve a coupled system of ODEs using `NDSolve`. In this system, one function is a scalar and another is a vector i.e. it contains multiple components. `NDSolve` does not work for the vector part. Here is a MWE

```
ClearAll;

(*declare cutoff*)
n = 1;

(*declare matrices*)

d1 = Table[If[i == j, i, 0], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
d2 = Table[If[i == j - 1, Sqrt[j], 0], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
d3 = Table[If[i == j + 1, Sqrt[j + 1], 0], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];

(*declare variables*)

c[t_] := Table[ToExpression["c" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 0, n}];
init = c[0] == Table[If[i == 0, 1, 0], {i, 0, n}];

(*setup differential equations*)

sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == 
    a[t] + c[t].d2.c[t] + c[t].d3.c[t], 
   c'[t] == -I*
     c[t].(d1 - (a[t] - Conjugate[a[t]])/2 d2 + 
         (a[t] - Conjugate[a[t]]))/2 d3), 
   a[0] == 1/Sqrt[2], init}, {a, c}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

This returns [image: a result like this], so c remains unevaluated. The solution for a is also suspect because I don't know what's happening to the coupling part. Plotting it confirms the same thing. What mistake am I making?
I could write out the equations explicitly but I'm going to need larger n values where this is not practical so I would prefer solving it in this matrix form. Thanks!

Comment: Don't give `c` a definition. Just remove the `c[t_] := Table[...]` part of your code.

Comment: I'm using that as a way to define c0, c1 etc. is there a problem with the way I've done it or is this kind of declaration a problem generally? It will be helpful if you can elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the first argument of NDSolve, you will see that `c[t]` does not exist anywhere, which is why NDSolve is unable to solve for `c`. Why do you need to define c0 etc.?

Comment: Another possibility is to use `{a, c[t]}` instead of `{a, c}`.

Comment: You are basically doing `NDSolve[{c0'[t] == 1, c1'[t] == 2, c0[0] == 1, c1[0] == 1}, c, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: your suggestion did solve the problem